# How can I add a new class style to an input field if it is valid (in Angular 4)

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm a newbie to Angular, I was working on Reactive Forms and I also included Bootstrap in the project, if an input text is valid and has class "ng-valid",
I need to add the class "has-success" to the parent div, so it will become green and takes the styles of Bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<input [ngClass]="{'has-success': true}" />
```

You can replace true for any variable of the component

Comment: Or a method call :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with ReactiveFormsModule, you can make something like this

In your **component** :

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
        myControl: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(4)]],
    });
}
```

and in your **template** :

```
<form [formGroup]="form" novalidate>
    <div [ngClass]="{'has-success': form.controls.myControl.valid}">
        <input formControlName="myControl" type="text"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you only have to set one class, instead of using `ngClass`, It seems easier to read, to just set the class like this

```
<div [class.has-success]="true">
```

Where you can replace the `true` with any expression.
If you need help targeting your child element, you can post your html - in a fiddle/plnkr if you want an easy copy/paste answer :)